# Java quickly access array item

Tags: java, arrays, hex

I'm doing a calculation that returns a long decimal, for example 4611686018427387904. I need to first convert it to hex and then chack an array of size (16) depending on the bits set.

So the above number gets converted to 0x40000000000000000L, this corresponds to the first index in the array. If the number is 0x0004000000000000L it corresponds to the 3rd index in the array.

My questions are:

1. Is there a quick way to convert a decimal to hex?
2. Is there a quick way to access an array depending on the bits set of the value (instead of using loops)?

Comment: You can effectively binary search for the first one bit in a long.

Comment: I don't understand why the second number is the "3rd index in the array" -- what do you mean by that?  And decimal and hex are two *external* representations of long -- you can output a decimal number or a hex number string from a long, but you don't "convert a long to hex" (unless you mean to a hex string), and it doesn't look like what you need to do here anyway.  Looks more like a masking problem.

Comment: @rcook It caught me out at first, but the values are different: in the second case there are three 0s in front of the 4. The first value has one two many 0s but that is a typo I think, or it is too big for `long`.

Comment: "Is there a quick way to access an array?" Maybe. Depends on the width of the array element type. Ideally, if it's 1-bit, you can very cheaply pack all its 16 values into a single `int` or `long`, with just 2 operations required to access it (e.g., `(values >>> i) & 0x1`, and avoiding the array bounds check. But if it's 2 to 4 bits per element, then 3 operations will be needed to access each one, and it might not be faster than a normal array lookup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, a guess: you have a long that you are viewing as 16 4-bit numbers.  You want to use each 4-bit number as an index into a 16-element array.

I think the fastest way to do this is going to be with a mask and some bit-shifting.  Both are fast operations.  If you mask out of the bottom, you don't have to shift the result after you mask.

There are 16 4-bit groupings in a long, so:

```
    long l = 1234;
    int[] results = new int[16];
    for (int i=15; i>=0; i--)
    {
        int index = (int)l & 0xF;
        results[i] = index;
        l = l >> 4;
    }
```

This gets your 16 indices from the right (lower-order) bits of your long, and you say the left (higher-order) bits are the first indices.  So this gets them all in reverse order and stores them accordingly.  Adjust for shorts or whatever you need, and this will be fast.

Warning: I have not run this code.  I mean it as a kind of java pseudo-code.

IN CASE YOU ARE NOT FAMILIAR WITH THE '&' OPERATOR: it gives you back the ones and zeros in the positions which have 1s in them, so & with 0xF will tell you whatever the lower-order 4 bits are.

Answer (score 1):

If the number is in the long range, use [Long.highestOneBit()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#highestOneBit%28long%29). Alternatively, BigInteger has a [bitLength()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#bitLength%28%29) method.

Answer (score 0):

Remember internally all primitives in Java is stored as binary.  The fact that it prints a decimal number when you pass it to System.out.println() is a view on that binary value.  So converting a decimal to hex if it's stored in a primitive (double, float, long, integer, short, byte) is already done.  If you want to convert that value to a hex string for display purposes you can Integer.toHexString( int ).

Java has an upper limit on array sizes which is an integer so 2^31 slots.  Anything over that and you'll have to use two or more structures and combine them.  I suppose that's sorta what you are doing.  But, if you are doing that maybe use a long, and Long.highestOneBit() could be a first index into an array of arrays where each slow is an array of potentially 2^31 slots.  Of course that isn't a particularly efficient structure for memory usage.  But that would give you a view that is potentially the size of a long.  You probably don't have enough memory for that, but who knows.

Comment: No, all primitives in Java are stored in binary; hex is a way of representing a binary number, just as decimal is.  We still don't know what the OP wants to do; there is insufficient information on the meaning of "3rd index in the array".

Comment: Fair enough.  I mostly think of hex and binary are the same because they are easier to translate between, but they aren't.  But yes technically you are right they are stored in binary.